# Regex word twice in string

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a way to detect the position for any all uppercase word(or parts of it) which appears twice in a string.
Examples - in Bold the position I want to detect:

- 00004 ADC SOME RANDOM WORDS **ADC** any other unrelated characters
- 02 SOME CANIT **CAN** any other unrelated 200
- 399 ADC0 FLAG **ADC0** some more words adc

What I have (and seems to work in online regex parsers) is this

```
p = re.compile('( [A-Z]{2,}[A-Z0-9]*).*(\1)')
match = p.search('0x0000 ADC asdf ADC')
print(match)
```

I tried different variations of blanks etc. but this produces Nonetype for match. Any hints what is wrong in this regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use raw strings when defining regex patterns. (See the [discussion of this issue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re) in the second and third paragraphs, and the explanation of [raw string notation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#raw-string-notation)) In your case, `'\1'` is getting interpreted as the single character `chr(1)`:

```
In [173]: '\1'
Out[173]: '\x01'

In [181]: list('\1')
Out[181]: ['\x01']
```

whereas, you want the two characters, a backslash followed by a 1:

```
In [180]: list(r'\1')
Out[180]: ['\\', '1']

In [176]: p = re.compile(r'( [A-Z]{2,}[A-Z0-9]*).*(\1)')

In [177]: p.search('0x0000 ADC asdf ADC')
Out[177]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0xb439770>
```

Note that if you wish to find as many such patterns as you can, then use non-greedy `.*?` instead of `.*`:

```
In [195]: [(match.start(), match.end()) for match in re.finditer(r'\b([A-Z]{2,}[A-Z0-9]*).*?(\1)', '0x0000 ADC asdf ADC0 ADC ADC0')]
Out[195]: [(7, 19), (21, 28)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Its `\\1` not `\1`

```
p = re.compile('( [A-Z]{2,}[A-Z0-9]*).*(\\1)')
```